# Why does dd only copy 128 bytes from /dev/random when I request more?

Tags: linux, command-line

I'm trying to understand the output of the `dd` command. I tried

`dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=512 count=1`

and got (as expected):

```
 1+0 records in
 1+0 records out
 512 bytes (512 B) copied, 2e-05 seconds, 26 MB/s
```

However when I tried

`dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/null bs=512 count=1`

I got

```
 0+1 records in
 0+1 records out
 128 bytes (128 B) copied, 0.00012 seconds, 1.1 MB/s
```

Why is it only copying 128 bytes?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/359599/why-is-my-dev-random-so-slow-when-using-dd for a more complete discussion of /dev/random and urandom

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `/dev/urandom`, or the "unblocking" random source.

`/dev/random` uses a kind of entropy pool to increase the randomness of the bit source.  This method will only return as many random bits/bytes as can be returned based on the entropy pool's state at the time, so if a hardware random number generator is used, this can sometimes be a constant.  From [the Linux manpage](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/random.4.html):

> The generator also keeps an estimate
>          of the number of bits of noise in the entropy pool.  From this entropy pool
>          random numbers are created.

The `/dev/urandom` file keeps reusing the internal pool as-is to generate a number as long as you need.  The side-effect of this is:  **do not use `/dev/urandom` for cryptographic purposes**, as it is less random than the bits produced by `/dev/random`.  See the manpage link above for details.

Comment: http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/

Answer (score 3):

Since reading `/dev/random` returns only the **amount of bytes** that is available, you have to specify block size **1**. In your example, you set block size to 512 which fails after the first read.

Therefore, the correct arguments that reads exactly 512 bytes is:

```
dd if=/dev/random of=filename bs=1 count=512
```

Note the command will block until there's enough entropy in the system to generate all the data. That's how `/dev/random` works. If you don't want to wait and you are fine with less entropy, use `/dev/urandom` instead. In vast majority of cases using `/dev/urandom` is preferred.

Comment: +1 for the explanation, though it should be said that with byte counts as high as 512 using `/dev/random` becomes virtually unusable, because the command can take many minutes to finish. Also, even with `bs=512 count=1` it seems that the call _still_ blocks if there _no_ bytes are available at all, correct? An alternative to switching `bs` and `count` values is to use `iflag=fullblock`; i.e., `bs=512 count=1 iflag=fullblock`.

Comment: IMHO, this answer should be merged into @Breakthrough's one. (It was the answer to my problem while Breakthrough's was not).